# Get specific instance of class from inside super class class method

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, singleton

```
+ (NSURLSessionDataTask *)login:(NSString*)email andPassword:(NSString*)password andCallback:(void (^)(NSArray *responseArray, NSError *error))block {


    if(![self hasInternet]){return nil;}
    NSLog(@"Session.login");
    [APIClient sharedClient].requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [[APIClient sharedClient].requestSerializer setValue:email forHTTPHeaderField:@"email"];
    [[APIClient sharedClient].requestSerializer setValue:password forHTTPHeaderField:@"password"];
    [[APIClient sharedClient].requestSerializer setValue:@"poop" forHTTPHeaderField:@"apikey"];


    return [[APIClient sharedClient] POST:@"/login" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * __unused task, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"session.loginWithEmail.response:%@",JSON);


        if([JSON objectForKey:@"user"]){
            NSMutableDictionary *user=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[[JSON objectForKey:@"user"] copy]];
            [user setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
            [[Session sharedInstance] startSession:user];
            if([[Session sharedInstance] isSessionActive]){

                if([JSON objectForKey:@"req_onboarding"]){
                    NSLog(@"session.onboard!=nil");
                    [Session sharedInstance].requiredOnboarding=[JSON objectForKey:@"req_onboarding"];
                }

                if (block) {
                    NSLog(@"session.login.block.success");
                    block(nil, nil);
                }
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Failed to set session");
            }


        }

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *__unused task, NSError *error) {
        if (block) {

            NSLog(@"Session.login.Fail");
            block([NSArray array], error);
        }
    }];
}
```

I needed a sub-class-able singleton in order to be able to have a abstracted session manager that does most of the lifting,but can still be subclassed so that multiple sessions can co-exist and still have the power of being available throughout my app. Im building somewhat of a demo of all my apps which is why this functionality is important.

All was going well until I realized that my api methods that are hosted in the super session class were referencing the singleton itself to set the session, this is a problem bc sharedInstance is referenced like so:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    NSLog(@"[Master sharedInstance]");
    id sharedInstance = nil;

    @synchronized(self) {
        NSLog(@"MS | synchronized(self)");

        NSString *instanceClass = NSStringFromClass(self);

        // Looking for existing instance
        sharedInstance = [_sharedInstances objectForKey:instanceClass];

        // If there's no instance – create one and add it to the dictionary
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            NSLog(@"MS | sharedInstance == nil");
            sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
            [_sharedInstances setObject:sharedInstance forKey:instanceClass];
            NSLog(@"MS | SharedInstances:%@",_sharedInstances);
        }
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

When it was just the one Session singleton I could get away with doing this in class methods: `[Session sharedInstance] isSessionActive]`

but now, its essential that  [______  sharedInstance] isSessionActive]; 
is a reference to the specific subclass calling the class method. Is it possible to retrieve reference the specific instance from within this class method shy of sending it as a param?

Comment: Is the `+login:andPassword:andCallback:` method your own code? Or is it code you can't mess with? If it's your own, I'd recommend changing it from a class method to an instance method, at which point you should be able to use `[self isSessionActive]` if `+login:andPassword:andCallback:` is defined on `Session`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the aim is to distribute a singleton per subclass of the super (probably abstract) class.  The `sharedInstance` code doesn't quite do that because this line:

```
sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
```

will create instances only of the superclass.  I think you want instances of the subclasses so that you get access to the overridden data and behavior.

If I understand your aim correctly, then the fix is simple:

```
sharedInstance = [[self allocWithZone:nil] init];  // notice "self"
```

With this, when you send `sharedInstance` to ClassA, you'll get a (single) instance of ClassA.  When you send it to ClassB, you'll get a (single) instance of ClassB.  With change I suggest, those will really be instances of the subclasses A and B, not an instance of the class they both inherit from.  If they've each overridden `isSessionActive` or any other superclass method, the caller will get the distinct, overridden implementation based on which class singleton they ask for.

Comment: It seems like the problem is how i was thinking about the problem, I decided instead to make session manager the singleton and have sessions not be singletons but rather a object that the sessionmanager holds and manages directly.

Comment: :-) when writing this initially, I was trying to decide whether to criticize your decision to have many "singletons", which is a little self-contradictory.  In my apps, I have model classes inherit from a class that knows how to do network operations to read and write them remotely.  This uses and discards sessions whose count is not controlled.

Comment: If Session is a singleton, but it is has a authUser property which can be passed in via a init ( subclasses of authUser with more properties) how can i go about accessing the subclass properties when calling [Session sharedInstance].user.[CUSTOM SSAuthUser property I know exists and is set]  from around my app?

Comment: It should work if the user property is declared publicly in the header.  I can't comment with specificity because I not sure the state of your code, whether you took my advice (which is still the correct advice for your question).